# Read groups with extensible attributes from Infoblox API (WAPI)

Tags: python, infobox

I have no experience with the InfoBlox API. I need to write a little script that reads all the configured networks with their extensible attributes (I only need the "Location" attribute).
After that I need to do some re-writing and posting via API to a different machine.

I searched the net and have found some examples but nothing where I can read all networks with the location attribute.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can answer all of it - perhaps you could add more detail about the precise problem you are facing...

However, I recommend the `requests` python library. You'll need to set some variables up with the url of your infoblox wapi as infoblox_address and the version. You can then query a network and get a json response with the external attributes.

```
attribs_request =  requests.get(infoblox_address + infoblox_version + network_reference  + "?_max_results=5&_return_fields=network,extattrs")

response = attribs_request.json()

print response['extattrs']['Location']['value']
```

You could query each network in your range and store the value in a list only when a value exists in the Location external attribute.